# Side by side diagrams with equations in between?

Tags: tikz-3dplot

What I am trying to do is take the 3-Simplex (tetrahedron) and put the 2-Simplex (Triangle) to the right of the tetrahedron (ultimately 3 of them but of course smaller) but separated by = and some +'s so that I would have something such as:

tetrahedron = triangle + triangle + triangle

I can't seem to get the positioning right, but also I am unsure of how to adjust these sizes.

Thanks for any help.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
       \begin{tikzpicture}[line join = round, line cap = round]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\factor}{1/sqrt(2)};
\coordinate [label=left:$A$] (A) at (-3,0,-2*\factor);
\coordinate [label=right:$B$] (B) at (2,0,-2*\factor);
\coordinate [label=above:$C$] (C) at (0,3,1*\factor);
\coordinate [label=below:$D$] (D) at (0,-1.75,1.75*\factor);

\draw[-,dashed] (A)--(B);
\draw[-,thick] (A)--(C);
\draw[-,thick] (A)--(D);
\draw[-,thick] (B)--(C);
\draw[-,thick] (B)--(D);
\draw[-,thick] (C)--(D);
\end{tikzpicture}

        \caption{}
        \label{fig:1flower}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
       \begin{tikzpicture}[line join = round, line cap = round]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\factor}{1/sqrt(2)};
\coordinate [label=left:$A$] (A) at (-3,0,-2*\factor);
\coordinate [label=right:$B$] (B) at (2,0,-2*\factor);
\coordinate [label=above:$C$] (C) at (0,3,1*\factor);

\draw[-,thick] (A)--(B);
\draw[-,thick] (A)--(C);
\draw[-,thick] (B)--(C);

\end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:3 Simplex}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{\ref{fig:1Simplex}: $1$ Simplex; \ref{fig:3flower}: $3$ flowers}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: To get the `subfigure`s horizontally aligned, remove the blank line between `\end{subfigure}` of subfigure (a) and `\begin{subfigure}` of subfigure (b).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you really need sub-figures here? Have a look on my very simple approach. Maybe it is of help for you.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usepackage{subcaption} % not needed any more

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
            \begin{tikzpicture}[line join = round, line cap = round,scale=.4,baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\factor}{1/sqrt(2)};
            \coordinate [label=left:$A$] (A) at (-3,0,-2*\factor);
            \coordinate [label=right:$B$] (B) at (2,0,-2*\factor);
            \coordinate [label=above:$C$] (C) at (0,3,1*\factor);
            \coordinate [label=below:$D$] (D) at (0,-1.75,1.75*\factor);            
            \draw[-,dashed] (A)--(B);
            \draw[-,thick] (A)--(C);
            \draw[-,thick] (A)--(D);
            \draw[-,thick] (B)--(C);
            \draw[-,thick] (B)--(D);
            \draw[-,thick] (C)--(D);
            \end{tikzpicture} 
            = 
            \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.3,line join = round, line cap = round,baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\factor}{1/sqrt(2)};
            \coordinate [label=left:$A$] (A) at (-3,0,-2*\factor);
            \coordinate [label=right:$B$] (B) at (2,0,-2*\factor);
            \coordinate [label=above:$C$] (C) at (0,3,1*\factor);           
            \draw[-,thick] (A)--(B);
            \draw[-,thick] (A)--(C);
            \draw[-,thick] (B)--(C);            
            \end{tikzpicture}
            +
            \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.3,line join = round, line cap = round,baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\factor}{1/sqrt(2)};
            \coordinate [label=left:$A$] (A) at (-3,0,-2*\factor);
            \coordinate [label=right:$B$] (B) at (2,0,-2*\factor);
            \coordinate [label=above:$C$] (C) at (0,3,1*\factor);           
            \draw[-,thick] (A)--(B);
            \draw[-,thick] (A)--(C);
            \draw[-,thick] (B)--(C);            
            \end{tikzpicture}
            +
            \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.3,line join = round, line cap = round,baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\factor}{1/sqrt(2)};
            \coordinate [label=left:$A$] (A) at (-3,0,-2*\factor);
            \coordinate [label=right:$B$] (B) at (2,0,-2*\factor);
            \coordinate [label=above:$C$] (C) at (0,3,1*\factor);           
            \draw[-,thick] (A)--(B);
            \draw[-,thick] (A)--(C);
            \draw[-,thick] (B)--(C);            
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption[Simplex and three flowers]{From left to right: Simplex and three flowers}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, that solves the problem.. thanks! I was trying to deconstruct a sub-figure example to do what you did. In case I get many triangles (from a large simplex, do you know to make some of the triangles go below the others (say two rows of two triangles for a total of 4 triangles)?